# Gas costs of the following contract

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, evm, fees

I'm calculating the gas costs of the following contract: `0x6001600190016007026005016002900460049060016021900560150160030260059007600303600960110a60005260086000f3`.

Disassembled versions:

```
contract Contract {
    function main() {
        var var0 = 0x04;
        var var1 = (0x05 + 0x07 * (0x01 + 0x01)) / 0x02;
        var var2 = 0x03 - (0x03 * 0x15) i% 0x05;
        memory[0x00:0x20] = 0x11 ** 0x09;
        return memory[0x00:0x08];
    }
}

label_0000:
    // Inputs[1] { @0032  memory[0x00:0x08] }
    0000    60  PUSH1 0x01
    0002    60  PUSH1 0x01
    0004    90  SWAP1
    0005    01  ADD
    0006    60  PUSH1 0x07
    0008    02  MUL
    0009    60  PUSH1 0x05
    000B    01  ADD
    000C    60  PUSH1 0x02
    000E    90  SWAP1
    000F    04  DIV
    0010    60  PUSH1 0x04
    0012    90  SWAP1
    0013    60  PUSH1 0x01
    0015    60  PUSH1 0x21
    0017    90  SWAP1
    0018    05  SDIV
    0019    60  PUSH1 0x15
    001B    01  ADD
    001C    60  PUSH1 0x03
    001E    02  MUL
    001F    60  PUSH1 0x05
    0021    90  SWAP1
    0022    07  SMOD
    0023    60  PUSH1 0x03
    0025    03  SUB
    0026    60  PUSH1 0x09
    0028    60  PUSH1 0x11
    002A    0A  EXP
    002B    60  PUSH1 0x00
    002D    52  MSTORE
    002E    60  PUSH1 0x08
    0030    60  PUSH1 0x00
    0032    F3  *RETURN
```

My estimation was (based on the recent fee schedule: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6mRqkBz3iWcOlRem_mO09GtSKEKrAsfO7Frgx18pNU/edit#gid=0)

```
3 x ADD + 2 x MUL + SUB + DIV + SDIV + SMOD + EXP + MSTORE + 17 x PUSH + 5 x SWAP =
3 x 3   + 2 x 5   + 3   + 5   + 5    + 5    + 60  + 6      + 17 x 3    + 5 x 3    =
169
```

Unfortunately, the corresponding VM test in the official go-ethereum repository (https://github.com/ethereum/tests/blob/ad2184adca367c0b68c65b44519dba16e1d0b9e2/VMTests/vmArithmeticTest/arith1.json) estimates this as 129.

Where have I over-counted 40 gas in this execution?

(please note transaction and call costs are not applicable for VM tests)

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be due to G_expbyte. If you look at the yellow paper (294) there are two different cases for EXP. One with exponent = 0 and one with exponent > 0 where G_expbyte is involved. However, G_expbyte is 50, so it doesn't fit the gap of 15.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That should be OK as the exponentiation is a non-zero one in this case `0x11 ** 0x09`.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to explain the gap? Afaik G_expbyte is 50.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, sorry, amending question!

Comment: Hi, it is not the answer, but I think you added one PUSH in your calculation and you forgot one SMOD instruction. May I ask you which tool do you use for disassembling?

Comment: I'm using this tool: https://ethervm.io/decompile

Comment: You're right - fixing now!!

Comment: What does `i%` mean? Why is the function return-value type not declared? What does `memory[...]` mean? Your code does not compile.

Comment: Also, you're going to experience a lot of truncation using those 8-bit constants.

Comment: In your calculation you forget to keep into consideration the memory expansion needed for MSTORE, take a look to the yellow paper. From 0 words to 1 word.

Comment: @goodvibration the "source code" for the test is given here https://github.com/ethereum/tests/blob/ad2184adca367c0b68c65b44519dba16e1d0b9e2/VMTests/vmArithmeticTest/arith1.json

Comment: @Briomkez - Bumped `MSTORE` to 6, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It is only an hypothesis: It is possible that from June to December the cost of some operations changed?

Comment: The VM test hasn't been changed from Jun 6 so unlikely :).

Comment: The cost of EXP when the exponent != 0 isn't 10+50, its 10+ceil(log256(exponent) * 50). That means the EXP here only costs 30 gas. That explains 30 of your overage, I'm not sure where the other 10 are

Comment: It is strange, because actually, if you take the "EXP" function presented here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.08660.pdf (which is outdated, because the W_expbyte cost 10 gas instead of 50 gas) you will get exactly 129 as expected ..

Comment: @Briomkez see my comment just before yours. EXP costs 10, EXPBYTE costs an amount based on value of the exponent.

Comment: I think that the formula you wrote does not correspond to the one of the  yellow paper https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf, which is `G_exp + G_expbyte * (1 + floor(log256(exponent)))`, so in this case (with exponent = `0x11`): `10 + 50 * (1) = 50`..
If the G_expbyte is set to 10 as in the linked paper you get exactly `20` which result in `129`

Comment: Ahh you're right, I was multiplying by 50 before flooring!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for EXP ([according to the yellow paper](http://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)) is the following one:

```
G_exp + G_expbyte * (1 + floor(log256(exponent)))
```

In your case exponent is equals to `0x09`. So if we use the current formula we will get:

```
10 + 50 * (1 + 0) = 60
```

As you said. However, apparently the test result were calculated with an old version in which [EIP160](http://%20github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-160.md) did not come into force. So the `G_expbyte` constant should be set to 10 (as stated here [in this accademic paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.08660.pdf)):

```
10 + 10 * (1) = 20
```

Which explains the result of 129 gas.

The name of the fork as pointed out by @flygoing is ["pre-Spurious Dragon fork"](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/18/hard-fork-no-4-spurious-dragon/).

Comment: Small correction, doesn't change the output, but EXP defines stack[0] as the base and stack[1] as the exponent, so the exponent is 0x09